# Analyze output of subprocess.Popen when piping to file

Tags: python

How can I analyze the output of my command, which I pipe to file, in real-time while the file is written?

This is what I have so far:

```
with open('output.log', 'w') as out:
    command = ['pg_dump', 'myDB']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

But this generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipe-to-file.py", line 95, in <module>
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Why is `p.stdout` equal to `None` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `subprocess.PIPE` for the `stdout` argument in order to get a file object, else it'll be `None`. That's why `p.stdout` equals to `None` in your code.

[From the DOC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

> Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

If you want to write `stdout` to a file while analyzing the output then you can use something like this.

```
with open('log', 'ab+') as out:
    p = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    std_out, std_error = p.communicate()

    # Do something with std_out
    # ...
    
    # Write to the file
    out.write( std_out )

    # You can use `splitlines()` to iterate over the lines.

    for line in std_out.splitlines():
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error=p.communicate()
```

Now you have your output,error.

Comment: Using `communicate()` will give you the result once the process is finished. Just read from `p.stdout` as the OP did but with `subprocess.PIPE` passed as you did.